# Load balancer takes a long time to establish a connection after ec2 instance replacement

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

The original problem I am trying to solve is when the load balancer starts forwarding requests to a newly-initialized ec2 instance, the first request to that new instance takes ~10 seconds. Subsequent requests are fine (~100 ms for the same request). I have also observed the browser taking a long time to load the web application after I replace the ec2 instance in the load balancer. I believe both problems likely have the same root cause, and since the latter problem is easier to explain and test, I will provide details on that problem.

I have the following infrastructure set up in AWS for this test:

- AMI that contains a web application, hosted in IIS
- ASG that points to that AMI with desired capacity = 1
- Target group with appropriate health check
- Application load balancer

Here is the test I run:

- Terminate the ec2 instance that is in the ASG
- Wait for the ASG to replace the ec2 instance
- Wait until the ASG reports that new instance as healthy
- Directly load the web application via the ec2 instance IP in Incognito Chrome browser (no load balancer) - loads in <100 ms
- Load the web application via the load balancer in Incognito Chrome browser - takes ~20 seconds

I can repeat this test for some time, usually with similar results. Eventually, it seems like something "clicks" and the site starts loading very fast through the load balancer.

What could cause this behavior? Is there something we could change in the load balancer configuration to resolve this issue? As noted above, the web application loads very quickly when accessed directly via the ec2 IP address, so it's not an issue with the application itself.

Comment: What are your health check settings in the LB?

Comment: The Target Group tied to the LB has a health check defined on a *.aspx page in the application. I think we are using default settings on that health check: protocol = HTTP, port = traffic port, healthy threshold = 5, unhealthy threshold = 2, timeout = 5, interval = 30, success codes = 200. The ASG has Health Check Type = EC2 and Health Check Grace Period = 300. I think that's all the health check settings. Let me know if I've overlooked something.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can control the setting from the load balancer to mark target health with minimum health threshold.

You can tune the initial response using these flags.

**HealthCheck Interval**

The amount of time between health checks of an individual instance, in seconds.

```
Valid values: 5 to 300

Default: 30
```

**Healthy Threshold**

The number of consecutive successful health checks that must occur before declaring an EC2 instance healthy.

```
Valid values: 2 to 10

Default: 10
```

So with the default value, the instance take to healthy that is `10*30`

To tune these configuration update the `HealthCheck Interval` to `5` and `Healthy Threshold` to `2` so it will take `10*2` to load balancer to mark the target healthy and route the traffic to the endpoint.

[elb-healthchecks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-healthchecks.html) or [target-group-health-checks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/target-group-health-checks.html)

Comment: I don't think this is my problem, at least not in its entirety. I changed my health check interval=5 and threshold=2 as you suggest, and then re-ran my test above. I observed the same behavior, where the site takes a while to connect the first time. Then connections were quick. But if I close the browser and come back 5-10 minutes later to reload the page, again it takes a while to establish that first connection. The ASG and Target Group all show as healthy during this time. I'm investigating a possible issue with the subnet right now.

Comment: If it's taking time on first time then it's not infra issue, which framework you are using? Did you enable cache in your frontend?

Comment: It's a web application hosted in IIS (c# .NET + JS). I think it's an issue with the ALB setup because the app loads very quickly when accessed directly via the ec2 IP address (even the first time). I only observe this behavior when accessing through the load balancer.

Comment: What is the memory of backend instances? And how do you access load balancr? Using DNS hosted some where else or from AWs? Try to `ns lookup DNs` then get the IP of load balancr and try with IP

Comment: Can you please post these metrics?

Answer (score 0):

My application was working fine when my ec2 was launched in a public subnet, which was attached to the application load balancer. There were no such latency issues.

When I moved my Ec2 to a private subnet and then attached that private subnet to ABL (application load balancer), this issue popped up.

The issue I faced was as follows: When I accessed my ec2 instance via Route 53 DNS which points to ABL for the first time, it took 1-2 minutes or (gateway timeout) to show the result and from the network tab in the browser "initial connection" was taking this time. After the first response, the remaining site works normally and gives a response in < 1 second.

I solve this problem by creating a new subnet in the same availability zone where my private subnet was associated and then attached the newly created subnet with ALB instead of the private subnet. This way I managed to solve this problem.

Example: testEc2 is created in subnet A (private subnet in us-east-1a) and then creates a new subnet B (public subnet in us-east-1a)(attached to internet gateway in route table).

In Load Balancer -> Edit subnet -> select us-east-1a and select public subnet and save.

I hope this will solve the above issue.